# Text With White Background

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication

I am designing a PCB and would like to have a white board with clear text in the middle like this:[image: Wanted Text]

I have looked up altium text options online and I believe this is the "boarder option", however altium only gives me the following options:

[image: Altium Text options]

If you could guide me in the right direction in how to enable this option or tell me how to get this text, that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: try the inverted button

Comment: you might need to draw a solid box under the text, or use unicode boxes: ▀▁▂▃▄▅▆▇█▉▊▋▌▍▎▏▐□▢▣▤▥▦▧▨▩▪▫▬▭▮▯▰▱▲△▶▷►▻▼▽◀◁◄◅◆◇

Comment: Don’t forget DFT and add lots of test point labels

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 what is DFT?

Comment: Read the list and see which one makes sense to use in any design. Then research that topic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT

Comment: I'm not familiar with Altium, but in terms of actual PCB fabrication I think what you're looking for is White Soldermask, Black Silkscreen. Would be worth checking with the PCB fab vendor you plan on using to verify that they offer that option.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Inverted" button under the "Font Type" heading:

[image]
[image]

Instead of placing the text in silkscreen, it will create an outline in silkscreen and allow the soldermask color to show through where the text is located. In other words, this gives you a border and transparent text.

If you want your entire board to be white, you'll need to instead specify white soldermask and black silkscreen when ordering the board from the manufacturer. In this case you would leave the "Inverted" button deselected. This won't give you the border though, this will just put black text on the overall white board.

[image]